# Regex not matching the digits, instead matches word

Tags: regex

The first command matches the string in the output

```
show output | grep 'minorThresh": "\w+"'
```

=>   `"minorThresh": "95",`

but the same with `\d`, is not showing any match

```
show output | grep 'minorThresh": "\d+"'
```

May I know what im doin wrong here.

Comment: What pattern are you trying to capture? "minorThresh95" ?

Comment: in order to use regex with grep add the -P parameter `grep -P ......`

Comment: pls ignore grep.. its the command line output of a device that I'm working on. its not actually grep, but another command which takes regex as input. I was trying to show an example. I was mainly trying to figure out why the  output string "minorThresh": "95", is not matching when I give "\d"

Comment: hi Wiktor, yeah I'm trying to match the entire string (95 is a variable number, so I wanted to give \d+ there, but somehow its not matching. When I give \w+ it matches)"

Answer (score 0):

```
show output | grep -P 'minorThresh : \d+'
```